# regexp proxy_pass on another port

Tags: regex, nginx

There is a web admin panel running on port 80 and there is a backend running on port 8081.
For example - there is a backend function localhost:8081/resource/users/add/$name/$pass. So, I need to redirect queries made to localhost:80/resource/users/add/ to localhost:8081/resource/users/add. 
Right now I'm using this conf:

```
       location ~^/resources/(?<fwd_path>.*)$ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/resources/$fwd_path;
    }
```

But i'm now quite sure this works properly

Comment: You don't need regexp. `proxy_pass http://localhost:9999;`

Comment: Well, but if I'll try to pass parameters it won't work then

Comment: In this case you should describe complete problem.

Comment: complete problem - there is a web admin interface running on 80 port, and there is backend running on 8081 port. I need to redirect all queries from web interface to backend.

Comment: That not a complete problem. All parameters are proxied by default. Show you config and examples. And do it in post, not comments.

Comment: I see you're from Moscow - may you contact me on facebook or skype, so I can desribe you a problem more efficently? Skype: glugzik, facebook : /frost.master.7

Comment: Writing and formulating problem will help *you* to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
location /resources/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
}
```

Comment: I don't get why should this work? If I access /resources/add it won'work then

Comment: It will, unless you hide some important part of config.

Comment: Well, ok. But, it will even with simple post queries like localhost/app?somethign=anything

Comment: Don't understand your comment

Comment: Opps. I wanna know if will it work with POST queries like localhost/app?something=anthing?

Comment: Yes. Why you just don't try and see it yourself?

Comment: Well, it doesn't work for some reason. The situation is - I've got a java restful service with no documentation or comments at all. I'm trying to get it work.